# How to save string value to another string in c# Windows Applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a user_name defined above in **class Form1 : Form**

And user_name is defined above as,

```
string user_name = "Rammy";
```

and i want to use this **user_name** in below line, but it is not executing, and giving error "**A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property**".

```
string copyright_bottom_text = user_name;
```

Can someone please help with this? I am using visual studio 2012.

Comment: can you share your whole class code

Answer (score 4):

move below line to a constructor or method

```
string copyright_bottom_text = user_name;
```

[Compiler Error CS0236](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5724t6za%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Instance fields cannot be used to initialize other instance fields
>   outside a method. If you are trying to initialize a variable outside a
>   method, consider performing the initialization inside the class
>   constructor. For more information, see Methods (C# Programming Guide).

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int i = 5;
   public int j = i;  // CS0236
   public int k;      // initialize in constructor

   MyClass()
   {
      k = i;
   }

   public static void Main()
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably try to access the user_name variable from a static method.
There are static and instance variables/methods. Static ones belongs to the class itself, and don't belong to instances created from that class. All instances an access the data through the class, but if you change it, it will change for all the instances -of course because it belongs to the class.
This is how it looks like:
class Something {
  private static string StaticString = "I belong to the class";
  ...
  //constructor
  ...
}
Then, when you make a instance of this class:
Something s = new Something();
You can't say 
string x = s.StaticString;
because it belongs to the class "Something", not the instance "s".
You can say however
string x = Something.StaticString;

In your example, you try to reach a instance variable, from a static method. This is the opposite of the above:
the user_name is unique in each instance (say, You can have a instance with name Joe, a instance with name Robert, etc). But you try to use it on a class level. The class doens't know anything about instances created based on it.
It's like when you give your dog a name, all dog should be called the same. It's not working.

Try to use static string as user_name, so it will compile, but it won't be correct.
Instead, keep the variable as a instance variable (not static), and use it in instance methods (not static). Keep in mind that you CAN use static methods and variables in instance methods, but you can't use instance variables or methnds in static methods.

I hope that helped. :)

Comment: But OP is not using static method. It is a field initialzer